# Solving a simple trigonometric equation in a range

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I would like to solve a simple trigonometric equation, for example $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2},$ but `Solve` gives the single solution obtained by using the inverse function `ArcSin`, while `Reduce` gives all solution in a form difficult to use.

I would like to have a list of substitutions like the output of `Solve`, for all solutions contained in a given range, for example $[0,2\pi):$

```
{{θ -> π/6}, {θ -> 5π/6}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give explicit ranges as inputs to `Solve`

```
Solve[{Sin[t] == 1/2, 0 <= t < 2 π}, t]
(* {{t -> π/6}, {t -> (5 π)/6}} *)
```

Comment: How simple! Thank you!